# Padding multiple columns in GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

In the following GroupLayout, the two columns (red and orange) have independent vertical alignment except that they share the same overall height and position.

[image: Desired layout]

Without a gap being added below the bottom orange item, that item becomes stretched vertically to match the overall height of the red column. This is unacceptable (it is a JComboBox and looks horrible). The only solution I have found is to add a fixed height gap (to the bottom of the orange items) that is precisely dimensioned. Is there a way to solve this problem dynamically (i.e. without using constants)?

Comment: `GroupLayout is a layout manager that was developed for GUI builders such as Matisse` and it's also been superseded by SpringLayout.  Consider using a GUI builder for this, and consider upgrading to SpringLayout. (P.S. We could use your code for this.)

Comment: @markspace: Good point about a [mcve]; `GroupLayout` since 1.6; `SpringLayout` since 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the `addComponent()` method. It has three additional 
parameters, namely minimum, preferred, and maximum size of the component.
For the `JComboBox` not to stretch vertically, you have to set the maximum size to `GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE` in the vertical group.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GroupLayoutMultipleColumns extends JFrame {

    public GroupLayoutMultipleColumns() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel green1 = createPanel(new Color(60, 170, 70));
        JPanel green2 = createPanel(new Color(60, 170, 70));
        JPanel red1 = createPanel(new Color(230, 0, 50));
        JPanel red2 = createPanel(new Color(230, 0, 50));
        JPanel red3 = createPanel(new Color(230, 0, 50));
        JPanel red4 = createPanel(new Color(230, 0, 50));

        JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
        JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();

        createLayout(green1, red1, red2, red3, red4,
                combo1, combo2, green2);

        setTitle("Multiple columns");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JPanel createPanel(Color col) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(col);
        return panel;
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(arg[1])
                                .addComponent(arg[2])
                                .addComponent(arg[3])
                                .addComponent(arg[4]))
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(arg[5])
                                .addComponent(arg[6])))
                .addComponent(arg[7])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                                        .addComponent(arg[3])
                                        .addComponent(arg[4]))
                                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(arg[5], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(arg[6], GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addComponent(arg[7])
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            GroupLayoutMultipleColumns ex = new GroupLayoutMultipleColumns();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]